# How do i run an executable every time i run my code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've seen it done on mac in xcode where you can edit the scheme to configure an external executable to run whenever you run your code.

How can this be achieved in Visual Studio? Can't seem to find out online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer, right click on the project you want to debug and select *Properties*.

Select *Debugging* group at right of panel, then modify *Command* item at the right. The default is `$(TargetPath)` which works for normal executable targets, but needs to be set to debug DLL for example. You might want to set also *Command argument* if the external executable needs some argument.